# VirtualBox - VM shows it uses 3% of CPU, but Host shows that VM uses 30%

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, cpu

My physical server has Intel Celeron with 2 cores and 3.5 GHz (temporarily, soon I'll replace it with Intel Core i7). For now, it has only 1 running VM. Ubuntu Server 18.04 is installed on Host, Ubuntu Server 22.04 is installed on VM. One core is allocated for VM. Why Host shows that VM uses 30% of CPU when VM shows it uses only 3% of CPU?

[image]

My system settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I noticed that uptime of VM and uptime of Host have a difference in almost three hours, but they were started in almost the same time.

Comment: Because running the guest isn’t the only thing your VM software does. It appears to have quite some data cached, is it perhaps doing lots of filesystem I/O? What about network traffic?

Comment: @DanielB Right now VM does nothing with filesystem. Current network status: https://imgur.com/a/WtHEvBy

Comment: @DanielB does it mean my VM won't use all 100% of allocated CPU?

Comment: Please add clarification (like that image) to your question. // I don’t quite get what you mean with your second comment, could you perhaps rephrase it?

Comment: @DanielB If I understand correctly, the host maintains the state of the machine even when idle. Therefore, the host shows that the VM is consuming 30% of the CPU. Does this mean that when the VM tries to use 100% of the CPU, it will actually only use 60-70% of the CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypervisor has to do a lot of stuff to help your guest run. VMs have emulated hardware that needs to be driven, even when the vCPU is idle. This is especially relevant regarding all virtual I/O and storage devices. All this “non-productive” work is called *overhead*. VMs don’t come for free.

I have a VM (QEMU, KVM) that runs a mail server. Even with the 4 guest vCPUs 98% idle (so <2% utilized), the hypervisor’s host process hovers at ~12% utilization—of 8 CPU cores.

It’s hard to put overhead into numbers, because different workloads have different characteristics.

---

> Does this mean that when the VM tries to use 100% of the CPU, it will actually only use 60-70% of the CPU?

Yes, but it’s slightly different. The guest will only have access to less than 100% of the host CPU because both the hypervisor and other host stuff still has to run. *Inside* the guest it will still appear to be 100% busy—simply because it cannot run any more programs on the CPU.

It’s somewhat like this (HV being the hypervisor and OS the host OS):

```
 ┌────────────────────────┐
 │Host CPU                │
 ├──┬──┬──────────────────┤
 │OS│HV│VM CPU            │
 └──┴──┴──────────────────┘
```

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you. What is the approximate maximum CPU that a VM can consume from what is allocated to it?

Comment: There’s no way to tell in general.

Answer (score 0):

The VM has no CPU, so its numbers are completely virtual.
A CPU in the VM is implemented as a thread running within the VirtualBox
process, and the threads are scheduled by the host operating system
to have their time-slices from the host CPU.

Therefore, CPU usage as reported by the VM is to be taken less seriously
than that reported by the host. Note also that the VM doesn't really
know much about the host CPU, only about its virtual CPU, and everything
it thinks it knows is probably false.